# ¿Como parsear correctamente un JSON con estructura desconocida?

Tags: java, json, java-8, jsonobject, jsonarray

Necesito obtener dos values, para guardarlos en una base de datos.
Desconozco la estructura exacta, incluso en otro JSON tiene un JSONArray mas, en otro JSON el JSONArray **resourseCharacteristic** tiene mas longitud y asi, lo que si se es que dentro del **resourseCharacteristic** viene un value **CUSTOMER_ID** y que el **relatedParty** siempre viene con mismas keys, diferentes values.

Es decir, tengo un JSON como el siguiente:

```
{
"event":{
   "eventType":"resourceCreation",
   "eventDateTime":"2020-12-17T16:54:59Z",
   "eventTS":"160823610",
   "sourceId":"181",
   "invokerId":"3570",
   "resource":{
      "id":"2020611",
      "name":"IPTV",
      "type":"9997",
      "state":"ACTIVE",
      "resourseCharacteristic":[
         {
            "name":"TEST_TYPE",
            "value":"IPTV"
         },
         {
            "name":"CUSTOMER_ID",
            "value":"99991389"
         },
         {
            "name":"EXTERNAL_CUSTOMER_ID",
            "value":"20821422"
         },
         {
            "name":"GRID",
            "value":"1"
         },
         {
            "name":"MULTICAST",
            "value":"Y"
         }
      ],
      "relatedParty":[
         {
            "id":"604",
            "description":"JUAN,JUAN",
            "role":"Customer"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

}

Es decir, necesito dos values:

1. Dentro de **resourseCharacteristic** necesito el value asociado al **CUSTOMER_ID**, es decir **99991389**.
2. Dentro de **relatedParty** necesito el **id**, es decir, **604**

Realmente, la pregunta seria ¿Se puede hacer de una forma mas simple, o si así esta bien?
Porque implemente algo, pero viendo el codigo creo que es demasiado "desorden" para obtener dos values.

Lo que implemente:

```
    String jsonString = "aqui estaria el json de arriba";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( jsonString );
    JSONObject resource = (JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONObject("event").get("resource");
    JSONArray resourseCh = (JSONArray) resource.get("resourseCharacteristic");

    JSONObject elementsCh;
    String serviceaccountid = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < resourseCh.length(); i++){
        elementsCh = resourseCh.getJSONObject(i);
        if ( elementsCh.get("name").equals("CUSTOMER_ID") ){
            serviceaccountid = (String) elementsCh.get("value");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Customer_ID -> " + serviceaccountid);

    JSONArray relatedParty = (JSONArray) resource.get("relatedParty");
    String flowid = (String) relatedParty.getJSONObject(0).get("id");
    System.out.println("ID -> " + flowid);
```

Aclaracion, la pregunto la dejo con ese titulo porque en si quiero saber la forma correcta de parsear o si lo que hice esta bien.

Estoy usando Java 8.

Desde ya, muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Espero que anden bien!

Comment: La búsqueda del valor en el que está `CUSTOMER_ID` es correcta como la tienes. A no ser que ese valor venga siempre en el segundo objeto JSON dentro del array, en cuyo caso puedes acceder directamente por su clave sin necesidad de iterar con un bucle, como haces con `relatedParty`. Convendría quizá poner un `break`  dentro del `if` para que no siga iterando cuando encuentre el dato. Y, en cuanto a la búsqueda del `id` es correcto sí y solo sí venga un solo objeto JSON dentro de `relatedParty` o si es seguro que el valor del id viene siempre en el primer objeto JSON del array.

Comment: @A.Cedano Genial entonces, pense que habia hecho un desastre. Muchas gracias por los consejos!

Comment: Lo extraño es que tu JSON venga de un modo tan complicado, cuando JSON existe para simplificar la vida. Por ejemplo, ¿no habría sido más fácil organizar el JSON así: `{"CUSTOMER_ID": "99991389"},` verificar si la propiedad `CUSTOMER_ID` existe y obtener el valor asociado a ella? Eso de usar un valor como identificación que es lo que intentas aquí revela un JSON mal diseñado.

Comment: @A.Cedano No creo el JSON yo. Para dar contexto, me hicieron crear un microservicio que lea mensajes, topicos de una cola Kafka y de ahi obtener estos datos para luego insertarlos en una base de datos. No habia trabajado con kafka antes, asi que no se de donde vienen estos json. Pero si, concuerdo con vos que de esa forma era mas facil de leer, y obtener su valor.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar librerias para parsear JSON o simplemente hacer
Map<String,Object> jsonAux = ((Map<String,Object>)jsonObject)